# Evaluating limit involving 0/0 and complex numbers

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

Evaluate for x=0:

$$ \frac{\left(e^{2πi}\right)^{x} - 1^{x}}{x} $$

The solution manual gives $2π$, but I can't find a way to get there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: last time i looked, $e^{2\pi i} =1.$

Comment: zhw Yes that's right, but you actually need to use the 2π to solve this limit here. See the answer below :)

Comment: @bobblebub,is this ${ e }^{ 2\pi  }\quad $ or ${ e }^{ 2\pi i }\quad $ because as zhw said it equal to 1?

Comment: @haqnatural It is $e^{2πi}$, and it's equal to 1. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { e }^{ x }-1 }{ x } =1 } $ so $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { \left( { e }^{ 2\pi  i } \right)  }^{ x }-{ 1 } }{ x }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { { e }^{ 2\pi xi } }-{ 1 } }{ 2\pi xi }  } \cdot 2\pi i =2\pi i \\ $$

Comment: Indeed I agree with this answer, but OP says that the answer should be 2pi

Comment: That is why i asked OP about that